# How to export a variable and log the details to the console at the same time?

Tags: echo

How to export a variable and log the details at the same time? For example, how to do the following in a one liner?

```
export myvar=$var1$var2$var3
echo $myvar
```

Comment: `export myvar=$var1$var2$var3 ; echo $myvar` or `export myvar=$var1$var2$var3 && echo $myvar` perhaps?

Comment: Thank you. That works.